# File descriptor usage in Spring Boot with Micrometer (and Elastic)

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, micrometer, spring-micrometer, elastic-apm

On various websites / blog posts, it is advertised that by using Spring Boot with Micrometer, we get tons of monitoring indicators out of the box, including the file descriptor usage.

For instance on https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector :

> Spring Boot 2 autoconfigures quite a few metrics for you, including: Datasource utilization, including :
>
> ...
>
> - HikariCP pool metrics
> - RabbitMQ connection factories
> - File descriptor usage
> - Logback: record the number of events logged to Logback at each level
>
> ...

I see most of the metrics, but right now I am interested in the "File descriptor usage" (because it seems I have a leak in my Spring Boot 2.5 application), and I am not finding the metric.

I've tried 2 things :

- locally (on Windows), using the JMX connector, and browsing the metrics using Jconsole
- once deployed (in a Docker image, based on Ubuntu-java), combined with Elastic APM agent, as described in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/metrics.html#metrics-micrometer-spring-boot

does "File descriptor usage" come under a special name ? or do I need to add a special dependency for this to be enabled ?

Thanks

====== **UPDATE**

As rightly pointed by @checketts , it seems from the source code that this metric would only be available on Unix systems (see https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/67c41db552cac463e44cd45545e5a7b8f3513f1b/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/system/FileDescriptorMetrics.java) . We see there that the metric would be recorded under `process.files`

So it's probably normal that I don't have it locally on Windows. But Then I should have it when it runs on Docker. But these are the only indicators I get for `process` in Elastic / Kibana :

[image]

Comment: What version of java is running in the docker container?

Comment: java version is 11

Comment: Which distribution? AdoptOoenJDK? Oracle?

Comment: # java --version
openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

Comment: All seems to be in order. At this point, I would recommend using WSL to try to debug it on your workstation, or running it locally in docker and trying to connect a debugger

Answer (score 1):

In looking at the code, it appears those meters are only bound when running on a unix operating system.

If you are testing this out on windows, I suspect you won't see the file descriptor metrics.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I've updated my question accordingly